# JQuery and Rails Calendar Plugins

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, appointment

Does anybody have experience with appointment scheduling calendars for a ruby on rails application? Should I instead be looking at pure JQuery plugins? I'm looking for something good for scheduling appointments.

Here's a few resources I found:

- http://dmix.ca/2009/06/weeklybuilder-a-weekly-calendar-plugin-for-rails/
- https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars?view=asciicast

List of several jquery ones:

- http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/10/jquery-calendar-date-pickers.html
- https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/

Answer (score 4):

I advise you to take a look at FullCalendar
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar

Well documented, works fine, probably the most popular Google Calendar like calendar. Written in jQuery and open source: MIT or GPLv2 license.

The integration with Rails is not difficult, you can look at some examples here:

https://github.com/bokmann/rails3_fullcalendar

https://github.com/vinsol/fullcalendar_rails

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the answer was to build a calendar out HTML such that clicking on a time slot div picks the time. Not too hard to do with some CSS and HTML, and jQuery.